# Files disappear after being moved by Dolphin from hard drive

Tags: 18.04, hard-drive, kde, dolphin

Totally new to Linux and Ubuntu and have run into a strange problem that I wasn't expecting.

I just installed Ubuntu yesterday (bionic) and also installed the KDE Plasma DE.
I wanted to move my personal files from an external storage drive (usb connection) to my linux desktop.

I used dolphin (drag and drop) to move (not copy) the files onto the desktop. At first, it would not let me move the folder (it contained lots of sub-folders and sub-sub-folders). My mistake, I didn't write down the error message.

After that I went in and tried to move the sub-folders individually which seemed to work - although it took longer than I remember it taking on Windows.
The sub-folders were successfully moved - there were no error messages - but later when I checked a large percentage of the files that were supposed to be inside are not there.

I have checked and there doesn't seem to be a pattern to which files have disappeared - i.e. some jpegs are there some have vanished, same situation with other file extensions.

I tried the show hidden file toggle in the dolphin menu with no luck either.

I'm not sure if all the files are lost. I'm also now worried about whether dolphin has problems, bugs, etc.

Is there some way to check if the files are still there and can be retrieved?

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect the source was corrupt before copying.

Comment: Thanks for sending a reply. It's appreciated.I was able to recover some of the same original files, put them on the same external drive and try to use Dolphin again. This time I was able to get them to transfer to the plasma desktop - but I used 'copy' not 'move. If the files were corrupted, I'm guessing it still wouldn't have worked (?)